# Implementing navigation in iOS applications

Tags: objective-c, ios, navigation

I've built an Xcode project which is an iPad and iPhone app that simply plays 4 different videos (.m4v files). I have an app icon and when the users touches it, the app opens an image (.png) with 4 buttons. If the user touches a button, the linked video is opened. Everything runs great.

Now I'd like to have a 5th button that, when activated by the user, brings the user to a new page that loads another image (png.). In addition I would have back button to return to the main page.

I can't figure it out. I searched various of my question but I don't think I'm asking it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter suggested, `UINavigationController` or modal controllers could be valid solution for your problem.

The implementation for a similar application logic could be done by means of storyboard (iOS 5) or manually (both through XIB and/or code).

In addition, starting from iOS 5, it's possible to implement your custom content controller (e.g. controllers like `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`). In this way you could implement your own custom navigation logic. For further info see `UIViewController` class reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!  It definitely helps. I will explore what you suggested. Thank You!!

Answer (score 4):

You should search for **UINavigationControllers** or **Presenting Modal View Controllers**. There are hundreds of tutorials on the web for this.

Also check the **Master-Detail** or **Utility** app templates in Xcode - they both have what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you peter. I had no clue where to look. i appreciate your time!